# Are <meta itemprop=""> tags still relevant in 2023?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

I have recently been interested in the SEO of my projects and have found many articles or forum posts that recommend using the `<meta itemprop="">` tags.

The fact is that these articles date for the most part from at least 4 to 5 years old.

The issue is that i can't really see myself the impact of adding those tags or not.

So today in 2023, are the `<meta itemprop="">` tags still taken into account by the different search engines or not?

Answer (score 0):

Search engines and social media sites support structured data. Microdata (itemprop) is one syntax that was initially popular, but JSON-LD is becoming the default syntax to use these days, partly due to Google recommending it.

Google still supports microdata and documents how it uses structured data in general:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery